# How to filter a filter in Dash - Python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, plotly-dash

I'am studying how to create a dashboard using python, It wasn't hard to create the Dash but now I'am stuck in how to apply a filter over another filter and both of them affect the grafics. At the code below, there is already created the dropdown of other filter but as I didn't knew how to apply the filter as I explained, I didn't created the function for it

I made a lot of tests with different grafics, so maybe the ones at this dash doens't make a lot of sense but it's not important right now.

[image: The dash I created]

Thats the database: https://github.com/stedy/Machine-Learning-with-R-datasets/blob/master/insurance.csv

Thats the code:

````
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, Input, Output
import plotly.express as px
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.CERULEAN]


app = Dash(__name__,external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)



df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\lucas\\Downloads\\insurance.csv"
)

fig = px.bar(df, x="age", y="bmi", color="region", barmode="group")

fig2=px.scatter(df, x="bmi",y="charges",color="smoker")

fig3=px.histogram(df,x="age",y="bmi",color="sex",marginal="rug", hover_data=df.columns)

filtro=df.region.unique()
filtro=np.append(filtro,"Regiões")

filtro2=df.sex.unique()
filtro2=np.append(filtro2,"Sexo")


app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    # All elements from the top of the page
    html.Div([    
        html.Div([
            html.H1(children='Gráfico de Barras'),

            html.Div(children='''
                BMI x Idade
            '''),
            dcc.Dropdown(filtro,value="Regiões",id="Filtro1"),

            dcc.Graph(
                id='graph1',
                figure=fig
            ),  
        ], className='col-md-6'),
    # New Div for all elements in the new 'row' of the page
        html.Div([
            html.H1(children='Regressão'),

            html.Div(children='''
                Relação entre fumantes e os planos de saúde mais caros
            '''),

            dcc.Dropdown(filtro2,value="Sexo",id="Filtro2"),

            dcc.Graph(
                id='graph2',
                figure=fig2
            ),  
        ], className='col-md-6'),
    ],className='row'),
    # New Div for all elements in the new 'row' of the page
    html.Div([
        html.H1(children='Histograma'),

        html.Div(children='''
            Histograma com dados da figura 1
        '''),

        dcc.Graph(
            id='graph3',
            figure=fig3
        ),  
    ]),
])

@app.callback(

    Output('graph1','figure'),
    Output('graph2','figure'),
    Output('graph3','figure'),

    Input('Filtro1','value'),


)

def update_output(value):

    if value == "Regiões":

        fig =px.bar(df, x="age", y="bmi", color="region", barmode="group")

        fig2=px.scatter(df, x="bmi",y="charges",color="smoker")

        fig3=px.histogram(df,x="age",y="bmi",color="sex",marginal="rug", hover_data=df.columns)


    else:

        tabela_filtrada = df.loc[df['region']==value, :]

        fig = px.bar(tabela_filtrada, x="age", y="bmi", color="region", barmode="group")

        fig2=px.scatter(tabela_filtrada, x="bmi",y="charges",color="smoker")

        fig3=px.histogram(tabela_filtrada,x="age",y="bmi",color="sex",marginal="rug", hover_data=df.columns)




    return fig, fig2, fig3


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)```
````

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two Dropdown in you callback and use it as filter to filter your data. Please refer below code:

```
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, Input, Output
import plotly.express as px
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.CERULEAN]


app = Dash(__name__,external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)



df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stedy/Machine-Learning-with-R-datasets/master/insurance.csv")


filtro=df.region.unique()

filtro2=df.sex.unique()


app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    # All elements from the top of the page
    html.Div([    
        html.Div([
            html.H1(children='Gráfico de Barras'),

            html.Div(children='''
                BMI x Idade
            '''),
            dcc.Dropdown(filtro,id="Filtro1",multi=True,value=[]),

            dcc.Graph(
                id='graph1',
                figure=fig
            ),  
        ], className='col-md-6'),
    # New Div for all elements in the new 'row' of the page
        html.Div([
            html.H1(children='Regressão'),

            html.Div(children='''
                Relação entre fumantes e os planos de saúde mais caros
            '''),

            dcc.Dropdown(filtro2,id="Filtro2",multi=True,value=[]),

            dcc.Graph(
                id='graph2',
                figure=fig2
            ),  
        ], className='col-md-6'),
    ],className='row'),
    # New Div for all elements in the new 'row' of the page
    html.Div([
        html.H1(children='Histograma'),

        html.Div(children='''
            Histograma com dados da figura 1
        '''),

        dcc.Graph(
            id='graph3',
            figure=fig3
        ),  
    ]),
])

@app.callback(

    Output('graph1','figure'),
    Output('graph2','figure'),
    Output('graph3','figure'),

    [Input('Filtro1','value'),
     Input('Filtro2','value')])

def update_output(regioes, sex):
    if regioes == [] and sex == []:
        dff_2 = df.copy()
    elif regioes != [] and sex != []:
        dff = df[df['region'].isin(regioes)]
        dff_2 = dff[dff['sex'].isin(sex)]
    elif regioes != [] and sex != []:
        dff_2 = df[df['region'].isin(regioes)]
    elif regioes == [] and sex != []:
        dff_2 = df[df['sex'].isin(sex)] 

    fig = px.bar(dff_2, x="age", y="bmi", color="region", barmode="group")

    fig2 = px.scatter(dff_2, x="bmi",y="charges",color="smoker")

    fig3 = px.histogram(dff_2,x="age",y="bmi",color="sex",marginal="rug", hover_data=dff_2.columns)

    return fig, fig2, fig3


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

So as you see, I added `value=[]` and `multi = True` in dropdown options and filtered data based on dropdown options.

Comment: Hi Friend, your answer helped me a lot, but now I'am trying to 6 filters, do you know how I can do it? I tryed using If but it didn't worked out well